# Sync react-router with mobx state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

Is there any way, how can I store react-router state (location, params, etc.) into my appState object as observable property? I am looking for something similar to [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux).

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to do this is to update the store representing your navigation state in the `componentWillMount` hooks of the routed components. When you do this a lot it doesn't feel really "clean" in the long run. For that reason we ended up not using react-router at all, and just parse routes ourselves (using `route-parser`). See this [blog](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-decouple-state-and-ui-a-k-a-you-dont-need-componentwillmount-cc90b787aa37) for the ideas behind it.

Based on the same ideas [mobx-router](https://github.com/kitze/mobx-router) was developed recently, you might give that a spin as well! Or just stick to `componentWillMount` if your routing is pretty trivial

Comment: can you give a sample of componentWillMount in your case ?